# Continuous Load via Snowpipe/External vs. Internal

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a vendor that is feeding me real-time data over SQS with CSV data in the body of the message. It's roughly one message/minute. The size of the body can vary greatly, but let's assume that it's under 512MB.

I first thought about writing a lambda function that's triggered by their SQS queue to upload to S3 and then use Snowpipe to load externally, but that seems like overkill to me. Wouldn't it just be easier to write the body locally to /tmp and then load internally?

I'm leaning towards loading internally, so I'm looking for a convincing argument to use Snowpipe / load externally instead. What would I be missing out on by not using Snowpipe?

Comment: What do you mean by load it locally?

Comment: Also, did you mean 512MB or 512KB?  512MB is pretty sizable and you'd be loading nearly 1TB of data every day.

Comment: @MikeWalton -  I edited, my fault. I meant load internally: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#copying-data-from-an-internal-location

I'm not loading that much data a day, but depending on the time of day, the body could contain 1 row or 300,000 rows. 512MB is the max amount of disk space for a lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An internal load, as referenced in that document link, takes the file, moves it to S3, and then runs a copy into statement.  There really isn't much difference between that and asking SQS/Lamdba to store the message on S3 and use Snowpipe to load it for you.  I think the easier and more efficient solution would be to ask Lambda to store the data on S3 (using something like boto3) and have Snowpipe load it.  With your method, you are downloading the message, storing it in /tmp, only to then push it back up to S3.  That's more movement of the data.

If these messages were smaller in size, I would have recommended that you use a direct connection within your Lambda function and use an insert statement, but this is much slower and 300k records would take too long.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks! While it wasn't explicit in the documentation, it makes sense that loading internally is also using S3.